# RecordCount vs BOF/EOF evaluation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, visual-studio-2008

I'm maintaining a set of code that has a wrapper class for SqlDataAdapter to load a System.Data.DataTable.  It has a generic function to determine if the DataTable "hasRecords".  I know it's a minor issue, but out of curiosity... Which is the faster method to use?

Existing:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property hasRecords() As Boolean
        Get
            hasRecords = CBool((CBool(BOF = True) And CBool(EOF = True)) = False)
        End Get
    End Property
```

or
Posssible new:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property hasRecords() As Boolean
        Get
            hasRecords = IIf(RecordCount > 0, True, False)
        End Get
    End Property
```

If RecordCount is defined as a fixed value in as a recordset property I would think the count would be faster as a single eval vs the multipart conversion/eval BOF/EOF method it is using.

Is there any other reason not to change it?

Comment: What type are we talking about? You mention both recordset and dataset.

Comment: A small nit-pick, but assuming BOF and EOF are Boolean, hasRecords = CBool((CBool(BOF = True) And CBool(EOF = True)) = False) could be rewritten as hasRecords = Not(BOF AndAlso EOF). Also, hasRecords = IIf(RecordCount > 0, True, False) could simply be hasRecords = (RecordCount > 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an unnecessary and potentially risky optimization; RecordCount may not always be available (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), while BOF and EOF should always return appropriate answers.  So your optimization potentially breaks behavior while likely providing only a minimal return in performance (which if you are really interested in, you should test).

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Potentially break - Pretty much my thoughts.  It's not a "must change" and I haven't touched it because "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".  I know the performance gain is ultra minor, but it was a bit of a curiosity when I stumbled upon it because the base code just looked so odd with the CBools.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the arithmetic involved,

```
hasRecords = Not(BOF AndAlso EOF)
```

versus

```
hasRecords = (RecordCount > 0)
```

it would seem the RecordCount test may be less effort. However, that would be a naive conclusion to reach. You'll need to do the timing yourself to see if there's any difference. My bold guess: On today's modern CPU - thru pipelining, branch prediction, and other advanced techniques - there will probably be no measurable difference.

---

BTW, Although you'll probably be fine with RecordCount, I've found that BOF/EOF to be more portable. Just sayin'.

Comment: OTOH, maybe Not(EOF AndAlso BOF) would execute a little faster since EOF is False more often than True for any given table with at least one row.